# Table coming on the Top of Div; how to bring the Table down

Tags: html, css, xhtml, html-table

I have a div in  the html and after the Div  and I have another div which contains the  HTml table Which is coming on the top of  div. How to bring the table down.

```
<div id='testupdate2' >Mynumber: ". $num." </div>
<div id="test">
  <table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 width="100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td id="Header" class="navUPD">MY number</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="tls" class="navUPD">MY DETAILS </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="mgmnt" class="navOFFTDUPD"> ADDR. MGMT </td>
        </tr>            
   </tbody>
  </table>  
</div>
```

How to bring the table down to the DIV?

Comment: The HTML is fine, the problem is probably in the CSS(which isnt here).

Comment: Actually, are you asking about the table being on top of the first div?
If so, we need you to show us what CSS you're using before we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To push your table off the top of your `<div id="test">` you can use CSS padding:

```
#test {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
#test table {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Padding sometimes doesn't work good in all browsers. I would rather use `margin-top` than `padding-top`.

Comment: @Ventus: By all means, use whichever gets the job done for you.  I prefer padding because it doesn't rely on the elements above to create the spacing.

Comment: Actually, you'd want either padding-top on the div to push the contents down from the border or margin-top on the table to push it down from the div... but yes, this.

Answer (score -1):

If you have something else in `<div id="test">` except that table and you want to table be always aligned to bottom of the div, you can do something like this in your CSS

```
#id{
  position: relative;
}
#id table{
  position: absolute; /*this is absolute to #id not to body tag*/
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

This should do the job, I think (I didn't check it).

Comment: -1: not OP's answer, and hack-ish. OP just wants the table to be separated from the top a bit.

Comment: sorry, seems I didn't understand fully his question

Comment: That's quite allright. If you're good-willed you'll get plenty more positive feedback than negative, and positive is worth much more.
The question wasn't that clear either... heh.